# How to count the number of embeded ref in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using node.js express and mongoose

i have following schema

```
var playerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    scores: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Score"
        }
    ]

});

var scoreSchema = mongoose.Schema({

        id: Number,
        score: Number,


});
```

now every player has array of scores. in the route app i need to count the number of scores

To count the number of players is easy i can count like this

```
app.get("/:id", function(req, res){
   Player.count({},function(err, count) {
       console.log(count);
       });
});
```

but to count the number of scores here is the problem how can i count them i am trying to do this but it throws an error

```
Player.findByID(req.params.id, function(err, data){
   data.scores.length // doesnt work
   data.scores.forEach // doesnt work
})
```

any ideas how to count the number of scores for any given player

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I found you an error in your code. You didn't write name of method incorrect.
To write

```
Player.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
```

Instead of

```
Player.findByID(req.params.id, function(err, data){
```